# How to get $E(X^2)$ through $E(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Here's my exercise:

A fair dice is thrown $n$ times till the result is six.
$S_n$ is the sum of the numbers of necessary throws.
Using Chebyshev's inequality, find an estimation to the probability that $\mid \frac{S_n}{n} \cdot 6 \mid < 0.1$ in cases of $n=100$ and $n=10000$.

I can first use geometrical distribution and easily find that if I wouldn't need the sum, just the number of throws, I could get $EX=6$ and $DX=30$. However I understand that I need the sum, therefore $S_n=\frac{X^2+X}{2}$. From there I get that $EX=\frac{E(X^2)+E(X)}{2}$ and here is my problem - I can't seem to find $E(X^2)$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$. So $E(X^2) = var(X) + (E(X))^2$. You know $E(X)$, so now you just need to look up (e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) what the variance of a geometric random variable is.

Comment: Wow, thanks! My coursemate also thanked you but I am struggling with finding DY now, can you give me any help?

Comment: That's a pleasure. What is DY?

Comment: It is variance in our textbooks.

Comment: And what is $Y$...? You don't define this random variable in your question.